# GridHelper axis different colours

Tags: three.js

Using GridHelper I understood that grid axes can be coloured. But both axis are assigned same colour. How to set different colours to each grid axis? Eg X/Y = Red/Green?

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt, it always helps to take a look at [the source code](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/helpers/GridHelper.js) (hooray for open-sourceness!). As you can see, the GridHelper simply does not support different colors per axis! It only supports different colors for the central line and the grid.

You might find the source code of [this demo](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_helpers.html) useful as well as it demonstrates usage of the GridHelper:

```
var helper = new THREE.GridHelper( 200, 10 );
helper.setColors( 0x0000ff, 0x808080 ); // blue central line, gray grid
helper.position.y = - 150;
scene.add( helper );
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe my question was vague. I know the GridHelper does not support what I wanted. I can see it would be easy enough to just rewrite my _own_ implementation of GridHelper to have different axes colours but the question was really to ask if there is some alternate trick to achieve the same thing without needing to do that?

Comment: Note: `THREE.GridHelper: setColors() has been deprecated, pass them in the constructor instead.` from [r76](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration-Guide)